# Best way to update a customized WP site (4.9.9 to current)?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, updates

The current site version is as follows:

- WP version 4.9.9 WP
- DB version 38590
- PHP version 5.2.4
- SQL version 5.0

The site has customized plug-ins and theme.  Using PHP compatibility checker, the theme is not compatible with PHP 7+.  The theme developer updated the version to run in WP 5.3.

What is the best method for me to migrate with less pain?

When I try to update WP to the latest version, the site breaks.

I tried using Duplicator, archive the live site and set it up on my comp with MAMP (PHP 7.2.10).  When I tried that, the site cannot load.   I can get MAMP to run PHP 5.2.4 but it won't run phpLiteAdmin.

[image: Error message]

What will be the best way?  Should I build the site from scratch and then install one plug-in at a time and customized them? There are plugins I can use to migrate posts and media.

If so, is there a way to migrate plugin set up info from live site to test site?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tryed with Updraft plus plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/

Comment: It will never be easy. My suggestion is just update everything, enable WP_DEBUG and start debugging exception after exception ;-)